# how to post comments to a post fetched from a database and displayed using a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there am trying to incorporate a forum like functionality into my website and users can post comments and others can reply to each comment. i have fetched the posts from the database and displayed them via a conditional while-loop.  the problem is that whenever i posts a comment for one post, the comment is entered in the database for each of all the comments displayed.  please help me on how to change this problem. Note that the php to insert the comments is also within the while() function because when i put it outside, the id for the post is not got and displays zero.

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT first_name,surname,post_id,post_body,post_date FROM  

users_posts INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id=users_posts.user_id     ORDER BY
post_date DESC LIMIT $start,$per_page";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$post_date=$row["post_date"];
$post_id=$row["post_id"];
$post_date=$row["post_date"];
$first_name=$row["first_name"];
$surname=$row["surname"];
post_body=$row["post_body"];
?>
//html to display users posts goes here
<?php
if(isset($_POST['publishcomment'])){
$postcomment=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['postcomment']);
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user_post_comments      (post_id,user_id,comment_date,comment_body) VALUES ('$post_id','$user_id','$date','$postcomment')")){
header("location:home.php");
}else{
$error="something went wrong";
}

}                    
}
}                         
?>
```

Comment: "Note that the php to insert the comments is also within the while() function". That'll be your problem then. One INSERT for every $post_id. You need to separate the code that draws the page from the code that responds to the postback. It only needs to run once. And it needs to get its variables from $_POST (i.e the information _submitted by the user_, which should include the relevant post ID) not from the loop. You also need to re-write the SQL using parameterised queries, because currently it's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks which could compromise your data.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is posted for each comment because you have the insert statement within the while loop and the `if(isset($_POST['publishcomment'])){` will always be true.

You should add a hidden field in the comment form with the post_id of the original comment.

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
```

Then change your if statement to this:

```
if ((isset($_POST['publishcomment'])) && ($_POST['current_post_id'] == $post_id)) {
```

Then it the ifstatement will only be true for the comment the user commented on.

Note: I am assuming you are creating a seperate form for each comment field for this scenario. Otherwise the hidden field would always be submitted and the ifstatement would again be true for each  comment.

Comment: rather than `&& ($_POST['current_post_id'] == $post_id)) `, it would be better just to remove the code which inserts into the DB from the while loop entirely, there's no reason at all for it to be inside it.